# Why are SharedPreferences ignored on some devices?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-room

I have a 2-step database migration in my app, using Room. The migration had to be done in two parts (v.2 -> 3 -> 4) because complex database operations using newly added tables had to be done between versions 3 and 4.
I have a `SharedPreferences` key-value pair to save the information when the user migrates. This is to ensure that the app won't try to migrate from 2 to 3 after it has already migrated to version 4.
The migration from 2 to 3 is meant to be run only when the user updates the app from the old version to the new version.
This has worked in every single one of our test devices, but Google Play's data is giving us a lot of crash reports for IllegalStateException, stating that the database tried to downgrade itself. This should NOT happen, should the SharedPreferences check work correctly.
For reference. Here's some of the migration code:

```
            if(!hasMigrated){
        if(NeedMigration.needMigrate(MyApplication.getAppContext())){
            ..
            try{
                //instantiate migration 2 to 3
                pdb=PreDatabase.getInstance(this);
                dRepo = new DayRepo(pdb, this, dayInstance);
                //db operations
                createDays();
                //store into SharedPrefs that we already migrated from 3
                NeedMigration.setHasMigrated(MyApplication.getAppContext());
            }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                Log.e("Database", "Already at version 4");
                ..
                return;
            }
            ..
            //instantiate migration from 3 to 4 (mig is in db.build)
            mdb = MyDatabase.getInstance(this);
            mRepo = Repository.fromContext(this);
            ..
        } else {
            /*
            If the user already has updated and the database exists in its newest state, skip straight to MyDatabase.java
            instantiation and load Day objects from database.
             */
            instantiateDatabase();
        }
        ..
        hasMigrated=true;
    }
```

The hasMigrated boolean is just a static boolean so that the app won't try to instantiate the database again during runtime. If NeedMigration.needMigrate returns false, it instead just instantiates the database at the current version.
Here is the NeedMigrate class:

```
        private static final String MIG_PREFS= "migration_preferences";
private static final String MIG_HAS_UPDATED ="has_updated_to_four";

//if yes (true) then yes need migrate
//if false then no! no migrate
public static boolean needMigrate(Context activity){
    //compare versioncode with sharedprefs
    final SharedPreferences preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(MIG_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final boolean needmig =  preferences.getBoolean(MIG_HAS_UPDATED, true);
    return needmig;
}

public static void setHasMigrated(Context activity){
    final SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(MIG_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //check if value exists
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    //false because if needMigrate is false then we dont need migrate
    edit.putBoolean(MIG_HAS_UPDATED, false);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Again let me clarify that this works perfectly fine on my test devices, but we're getting a lot of crash reports from Google implying that the database tried to run at the previous version:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>           at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:101)
>             at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onDowngrade         (RoomOpenHelper.java:113)
>             at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onDowngrade
>   (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:144)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked
>   (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
>   (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:2)   at
>   androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase
>   (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)   at
>   androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
>   (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)   at
>   androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query (RoomDatabase.java:256)   at
>   androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query (DBUtil.java:54)   at
>   fi......controllers.database_controller.MealGroupDao_..PreDatabase_Impl.getMealGroupsInDay
>   (MealGroupDao_..PreDatabase_Impl.java:157)   at
>   fi.....DayRepo.lambda$populateDayCache$0 (DayRepo.java:301)   at
>   fi.....controllers.database_controller.repos.-$$Lambda$DayRepo$gQGLM0kHLZLeLseqjFzeMTTO2fw.run
>   (-.java:8)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   at java.lang.Thread.run
>   (Thread.java:764)

We just got a review saying "Can't open app"and I suspect that this is the reason.

Why is this SharedPreference check ignored, or does it just return a wrong value ? Is this a context-related issue or perhaps related to the fact that the NeedMigration class is static?
I have tried:

- Changing context from activity to application context
- moving the setHasMigrated call to happen before the database 2 to 3 update (DID NOT WORK...)
- Adding try/catch blocks in a lot of places

Comment: Why aren't you using room migrations, which will take care of all this for you?  You could even trivially create a 2->4 migration by calling out to a 2->3 migration then a 3->4 migration.

Comment: The database classes are using RoomDatabase. As I stated, a 2-4 migration wasn't really possible because of the complex database operations needed to be done between migrations 2-3 and 3-4. The database structure changed quite dramatically

Comment: And Room has a migration system built in.  And you can easily create a 2->4 migration in it by migrating 2->3 then 3->4 using it.  Rolling your own is just creating problems for you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#java

Comment: Please stick to the topic and answer my question. If you want to, I can edit the question to include some of my migration code so you would understand it better.

Comment: The reason I made this in two parts is because in the first step i added a new table using the Migration class. After that I needed to add a lot of data to that new table using the DAOs I created in the first class. This would not work like you suggested, because Room wouldn't be able to use the DAO for the new table before the Room class was actually built. Without the DAOs I would have hundreds of lines of code in pure SQLite because of the logic required to add the data, and I don't want that.

Comment: Also note that your problem is in a downgrade.  Forget the shared preferences-  you shouldn't be calling downgrade at all, even if you were on v3-  why not just move to 4?  Something else is screwy here.

Comment: I don't have a problem with doing it in 2 parts.  Do it in 2 parts using the built in room migrations.  You write a v2-v3 class.  You write a v3-v4 class.  Then you write a v2-v4 class that instantiates both of the previous and calls one after the other.  Then room will handle everything for you.

Comment: Would the v3-v4 class be able to use the DAO for the table created in v2-v3? Can I use outside classes within the migrate method? (As the logic needed to fill the table with data is in a class, there is a different amount of data to be added depending on the user's version of the app so those checks also need to be made)

Comment: Why are you even using SharedPreferences? Room has built-in support for migrations. Yes, even for complex changes.

Comment: Yes, if they're written in raw SQLite. Please check out my newest question.